# group by clause query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have  a table with values like this,

i want to group by cusotmer name where as sum of the local amount should exceed 50000 else i need to delete those records which do not satisfy?

how to achieve it in sql server 2005?

```
TRN 259 3   9/9/2010    6622    68667(Rs) ABHIJIT KATARE  
TRN 260 3   9/9/2010    6622    14635(Rs)   ABHIJIT KATARE  
TRN 235 3   9/9/2010    6586    68128   AJAY PARASRAMPURIA  
TRN 236 3   9/9/2010    6586    14490   AJAY PARASRAMPURIA  
TRN 257 3   9/9/2010    6621    68667   ANAND DESAI  
TRN 258 3   9/9/2010    6621    14635   ANAND DESAI  
TRN 287 3   9/9/2010    6817    119095  ANAND KATAKAM  
TRN 242 3   9/9/2010    6594    95689   ANILKUMAR MUTHUNPARA  
TRN 211 3   9/9/2010    6507    52239   ARBIND KUMAR GUPTA  
TRN 212 3   9/9/2010    6538    63183   ASHOK KELKAR  
TRN 185 3   9/9/2010    6431    140610  BANSAL Y.K  
TRN 186 3   9/9/2010    6431    46845   BANSAL Y.K  
TRN 248 3   9/9/2010    6600    72565   BENNO HANS LUKE
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the customers that have less than 50000:

```
select CustomerName, sum(LocalAmount)
from MyTable
group by CustomerName
having sum(LocalAmount) <= 50000
```

Note that you are better off grouping by `CustomerID` if there is one, as there could be duplicate names. Then, you can delete by doing this:

```
delete from MyTable 
where CustomerID in (
    select CustomerID 
    from MyTable
    group by CustomerID 
    having sum(LocalAmount) <= 50000
)
```

Comment: how do you know there is a CustomerID column? and even if there is one, it there might be several IDs that have the same display name.  I've seen this in systems where one customer buys another, they change the display name but the FKs still use the original ID

Comment: I don't know this, it is a supposition - that is why first example is using customer name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the select:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
GROUP BY CustomerName
HAVING SUM(LocalAmount) > 50000
```

Try this for delete (modified version of @RedFilter's):

```
delete from MyTable 
where CustomerName in (
    select CustomerName 
    from Table
    group by CustomerName 
    having sum(LocalAmount) <= 50000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from MyTable group by CustomerName having sum(LocalAmount) > 50000`

Answer (score 0):

to see the good rows use:

```
SELECT
    cusotmerName ,SUM(localAmount)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY cusotmerName
    HAVING SUM(localAmount)>50000
```

to delete the bad rows use:

```
DELETE YourTable
WHERE
    CustomerName IN (SELECT
                             cusotmerName
                             FROM YourTable
                             GROUP BY cusotmerName
                             HAVING SUM(localAmount)<50000 
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

this syntax looks a bit weird but it works!

```
;with cte as
(
select sum(LocalAmount) over (partition by cname) s 
from yourtable
)
delete from cte where s <= 50000
```